# How common is it for graduate schools to allow admission to be deferred for a year

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, career-path

I have a number of Arabic friends applying to graduate school and due to their situation, they tell me they intend to apply and then get a deferment for the next year. I am curious how common it is for grad schools to allow this.

I ask this because I am considering applying to PhD program in statistics and I'm starting a Master's program this fall. My GRE scores will expire at the end of the year and so I am considering applying to PhD programs this fall (with the expectation of deferring acceptance for the following year, which will be right after I get my Masters).

Most of the schools I look at seem to discourage deferment, and the only reason why I can think maybe the Arabic students don't run into difficulties is b/c they don't require any funding (they tend to be on the KSA scholarships).

Just curious if anyone can give me a realistic idea of how grad schools generally deal with deferments?

TIA,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general trend for deferrals is to make them available, but not automatic—usually, you have to explain exactly *why* you want the deferral, and what you plan to do in the intervening time. For example, doing a volunteer year (for example, for a Peace Corps-like organization) or accepting a prestigious international fellowship are usually acceptable reasons for a deferral. On the other hand, accepting a job offer for a year would normally not be considered grounds for a deferral.  However, I think this is a policy that differs from department to department and institution to institution, so definitely check with them first!

The reason for this is that deferrals impact *two* admission classes: the current one, as well as the following one. You can't admit extra students, because you have the deferring students from the present year, plus you're now "short" a student for the new incoming class.

Comment: Thank-you: that was pretty much my impression. I've been in academics for awhile and can't remember ever hearing a student granted a deferral. However b/c all of these students acted like it was commonplace, I naturally wondered if things might have changed.

Comment: @MattBrenneman: Immigration might be a different issue altogether—it's certainly a significant obstacle for students from many countries these days, and could also be an "acceptable" reason to defer. (Depends on the school.)